# Mass update metadata in all items (files and folders) in a document library

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata

This is my first question here, so apologies if it is a duplicate. I'm trying to write PowerShell code to mass-update a managed metadata property, doing something like this:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$caml = '<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="My_x0020_Column" /><Value Type="Text">My Column</Value></BeginsWith></Where>' 
$query.Query = $caml 

$listItems = $list.GetItems($query)

foreach($item in $listItems)
{
    #Cast to SPListItem to avoid ambiguous overload error
    $spItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item;

    #Get the taxonomy field for the list item
    $taxField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["My Store"]

    #Set the field's value using the term
    $taxField.SetFieldValue($spItem,$term)
    $spItem.Update()
}
```

However, this only modifies files in the root directory. How can I traverse through all files and folders in the library?

Comment: Have you tried SPList.GetItems() method instead of iterating over SPList.Items? Your code for retrieving the list items is missing above

Comment: I updated with more of my code. I call a query that searches for any column value of My Column.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't just reaching the default spquery row limit?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm starting to test with a very small sample size.